# Configuring socket.io on Cloud Foundry

Tags: socket.io, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to set up a socket.io connection on Cloud Foundry via IBM Toolchains. I've gone through the [docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/supporting-websockets.html) and have been trying to get socket.io to connect to port 4443. I'm kind of new to this so would appreciate if you could provide some pointers on how to set up socket.io on the CF env as I still struggle to digest parts of the documentation. Code can be found below.

```js
//---------------------------
// app.js
//---------------------------

// Start the app on cloud foundry
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log("Server is starting on " + appEnv.url);
});


// Connect socket.io
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 console.log('a user connected');
});

var port = 4443;  // Cloud Foundry assigned port for TCP/WebSocket communications

server.listen(port, function() {
 console.log('listening on ', port);
});
```

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io.connect("https://0.0.0.0:4443");
</script>
```

My understanding after going through the socket.io docs is that the IP provided should be the `location.hostname` which I believe to be `0.0.0.0` in this case as it refers to the IP which the express instance for the app is listening on. Not too sure about this though.

By changing it to below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.slim.js"></script>
<script> var socket = io(); </script>
```

The error changes to a 404 error with the following error being repeated: "https://realtimetrafficanalysisaks.mybluemix.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=". I've checked regarding the `app` and `server` settings but can't seem to pinpoint the error

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to sort this out with socket.io due to the port issue but I was able to get it running using the express-ws package